3DS OutScale programmatic user
Outscale documentation says:

The root user must create access keys manually for each user.


It is recommended to renew your access key regularly.

Is there a way to create user fully programmatically ?
Motivation:

I want to create API Access Key for programmatic user (softwares). Doing it manually is too limiting.
How do we regularly rotate the Keys for my softwares ? Manually ?
If it must be done manually, how can it be delegated to colleagues without granting them root access ?


For EIM users it can be done like this
from osc_sdk_python import Gateway    
gw = Gateway(...)
gw.CreateUser(UserName="Alice")
new_key= gw.CreateAccessKey(UserName="Alice")

EIM users cannot access all Outscale services (ex: OOS).
For root (account) users, the creation cannot to be automated.
The key rotation (EIM and root users) can be done like this:
from osc_sdk_python import Gateway    
gw = Gateway(...)
new_key= gw.CreateAccessKey()
gw.DeleteAccessKey(AccessKeyId=old_key["AccessKeyId"])

